# How To resolve Error code -1202 for iTunes/InApp Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I am installing inApp purchase in My app.Yesterday code was running fine and I tested it under sandbox environment. But today when i try to purchase product I am getting -1202 Error from iTunes.

I also googled for  answer and refer apple doc but didn't find error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem on a customer's pc:
the problem was caued by wrong date/time or zone settings.. I changed pc settings with the correct timezone (and obviously date and time), rebooted and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you.This works.I accidentally changed my iPod date to 2002.I changed it back and no more error code !!!!